# Extract all the data of a particular month from dataset of different years

Tags: python, pandas, preprocessing

In a dataset containing temperatures of different years and I want to extract data of particular month from all different years in single liner code what is the syntax? To extract all the data from a single month the syntax is :
`df['Temperature'].loc['2010-08']` 
It is always year followed by month.What if I want to extract 2010 & 2011 years temperatures in August in single line.

Comment: Kindly reframe your question a little bit more.. thanks.., Simply add a new column of month,year etc.. and then the problem becomes trivial, isn't.... Spoiler use group to get the statistics air do what ever you want.. https://www.shanelynn.ie/select-pandas-dataframe-rows-and-columns-using-iloc-loc-and-ix/

Answer (score 1):

```
df.loc[df['Temperature'].isin(['2010-08', '2011-08'])]
```

isin() will help in setting filter for multiple values.

The other way is to use regex to extract data of particular month from different years:

```
import re
df['Temperature'].filter(lambda x: re.match('-08$', x))
```

It will check if the value ends with -08 (in this case, if the month is August) and select only such records.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I don't want to explicitly mention the year

Comment: Okay. You need to use regex in that case. I'll update in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `between` over the required months for filtering, based on you `datetime` column:

```
Aug= df['datetime'].dt.month.between(8,8)
df_Aug = df.loc[Aug]
```